# Inconsistent execution times in Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas

Note: I would have checked Mike Brandt's answer if I could have since he caught my dumb mistake on the dead/live pixel ratio.  But Ken gets the nod for generally good advice.

I'm trying to debug some performance issues with a Conway's game of life in a Canvas element and I'm getting some very strange performance issues.

I'm getting about 4-12 FPS and benchmarking of the drawing functions indicates that the overall performance should be able to go up to 60 FPS.

Below is the Canvas drawing code.  updateBgCanvas is being called at about 30FPS by RequestAnimationFrame.  The whole thing is being run and perf tested in Chrome 28.0.1500.70.

(my apologies for the messy code, I've been hacking the code up into smaller subunits to get greater granularity in the performance profiler without much regard to good coding technique)

Unsurprisingly, the Canvas drawing functions (fillDead and fillLive are the biggest CPU hogs but here's where it gets bizarre.  fillLive consumes 5-6% of the CPU time (about what I would expect from the fillRect benchmarking I did) and fillDead eats a whopping 36-38% of the CPU time.  These are identical functions except for a conditional test against 1 or 0.

I've tried swapping the calling order in the parent function and the colors being used for fill and fillDead consistently takes 6-7 times longer to call than the nearly identical fillLive.  I'm completely at a loss for why this would be.

Any suggestions?

```
  window.bgVars = {
     "about": "The background is the famous Conway Game of Life",
     "_Canvas": {},
     "_Ctx": {},
     "xBlockSize": 5,
     "yBlockSize": 5,
     "xBlocks": 0,
     "yBlocks": 0,
     "bornVals": [3],
     "stayAliveVals": [2, 3],
     "cGrid": [],
     "cGrid2": [],
     "cL": 0,
     "initBgVars" : function(iCanvas, iCtx){
        console.log(this.xBlockSize);
        this._Canvas = iCanvas;
        this._Ctx = iCtx;
        this.cGrid = [];
        this.cGrid2 = [];
        this.xBlocks = Math.round(myCanvas.width/this.xBlockSize) + 1;
        this.yBlocks = Math.round(myCanvas.height/this.yBlockSize) + 1;
        for(var rep=0;rep<(this.xBlocks * this.yBlocks);rep++){
           this.cGrid.push(Math.round(Math.random()*0.8));
        }
        this.cGrid2.length = this.cGrid.length;
     },
     "cirInd": function(index){
        //returns modulus, array-wrapping value to implement circular array
        if(index<0){index+=this.cGrid.length;}
        return index%this.cGrid.length;
     },
     "calcNeighbors": function(rep){
        var foo = this.xBlocks;
        var neighbors = this.cGrid[this.cirInd(rep-foo-1)] + this.cGrid[this.cirInd(rep-foo)] + this.cGrid[this.cirInd(rep-foo+1)] + this.cGrid[this.cirInd(rep-1)] + this.cGrid[this.cirInd(rep+1)] + this.cGrid[this.cirInd(rep+foo-1)] + this.cGrid[this.cirInd(rep+foo)] + this.cGrid[this.cirInd(rep+foo+1)];
        return neighbors;
     },
     "refreshGrid": function(){
        for(var rep=0;rep<this.cGrid.length;rep++){
           if(Math.random()<0.0002){this.cGrid2[rep] = 1;}
           this.cGrid[rep] = this.cGrid2[rep];
        }
     },
     "lifeRules": function(rep, neighbors){
           if(this.cGrid[rep] == 1){  //stay alive rules
              for(var rep2=0;rep2<this.stayAliveVals.length;rep2++){
                 if(neighbors==this.stayAliveVals[rep2]){this.cGrid2[rep] = 1;}
              }
           }
           if(this.cGrid[rep] == 0){  //'born' rules
              for(var rep2=0;rep2<this.bornVals.length;rep2++){
                 if(neighbors==this.bornVals[rep2]){this.cGrid2[rep] = 1;}
              }
           }          
     },
     "fillDead": function(){
        for(var rep=0;rep<this.cGrid.length;rep++){
           if(this.cGrid[rep] == 0){
              this._Ctx.fillRect((rep%this.xBlocks)*this.xBlockSize, Math.floor(rep/this.xBlocks)*this.yBlockSize, this.xBlockSize, this.yBlockSize);
           }
        }          
     },
     "fillLive": function(){
        for(var rep=0;rep<this.cGrid.length;rep++){
           if(this.cGrid[rep] == 1){
              this._Ctx.fillRect((rep%this.xBlocks)*this.xBlockSize, Math.floor(rep/this.xBlocks)*this.yBlockSize, this.xBlockSize, this.yBlockSize);
           }
        }          
     },
     "updateBgCanvas": function(){
        //fill live squares
        this._Ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(130, 0, 0)';
        this.fillLive();
        //fill dead squares
        this._Ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(100, 0, 0)';
        this.fillDead();
        //calculate next generation to buffer
        for(var rep=0;rep<this.cGrid.length;rep++){
           //add up the live squares in the 8 neighbor blocks
           var neighbors = this.calcNeighbors(rep);
           this.cGrid2[rep] = 0;
           //implement GoL ruleset
           this.lifeRules(rep, neighbors);
        }
        //seed with random noise to keep dynamic and copy to display buffer
        this.refreshGrid();
     }
  }
```

edits to math functions suggested by Ken, copying parent object vars to local vars, giving about 16% perf gain in the math functions, about 4% overall:

```
     "cirInd": function(index, mod){
        //returns modulus, array-wrapping value to implement circular array
        if(index<0){index+=mod;}
        return index%mod;
     },
     "calcNeighbors": function(rep){
        var foo = this.xBlocks;
        var grid = this.cGrid;
        var mod = grid.length;
        var neighbors = grid[this.cirInd(rep-foo-1, mod)] + grid[this.cirInd(rep-foo, mod)] + grid[this.cirInd(rep-foo+1, mod)] + grid[this.cirInd(rep-1, mod)] + grid[this.cirInd(rep+1, mod)] + grid[this.cirInd(rep+foo-1, mod)] + grid[this.cirInd(rep+foo, mod)] + grid[this.cirInd(rep+foo+1, mod)];
        return neighbors;
     },
```

Comment: Have you counted how many times you actually execute the code in the conditional in each case (i.e. does cGrid contain significantly more 0's than 1's)? I would think the only time you would expect performance to be the same between the two functions is when cGrid has roughly equal numbers of 1's and 0's.

Comment: That's possible.  I was eyeballing the dead/live pixel ratio during the profiling time window and it seemed pretty even but it could just be an optical illusion.  I'll do a quick check..

Comment: Yep, my eyes are dirty, dirty liars.  The dead/live pixel ration is only about 4:1 but it seems to be the likely cause.  Thanks!

Comment: you should combine fillDead and fillAlive and maybe also updateBgCanvas: currently you go three times through the array; also instead of `this.cGrid` eg. you may use vars to save the `this` lookups

Comment: Originally, it was all one function, I broke it out to subroutines to granularize the profiling.  Since there's such a large discrepancy between the number of live and dead pixels, i just rewrote it to do a dead color flood fill and only draw the 'live' pixels.
I've also been playing around with using vars to reduce lookup costs but didn't see much of a performance gain from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give an example of what you can do to improve the performance try to replace the fillDead function with this modifcation:

```
"fillDead": function(){

   /// localize to vars so interpreter doesn't
   /// have to walk of the branches all the time:
   var cGrid = this.cGrid, ctx = this._Ctx,
       xBlocks = this.xBlocks, xBlockSize = this.xBlockSize,
       yBlockSize = this.yBlockSize,
       rep = cGrid.length - 1;

   /// while loops are generally faster than for loops
   while(rep--) 
      if(cGrid[rep] == 0){
         ctx.fillRect((rep%xBlocks) * xBlockSize, ((rep/xBlocks)|0) * yBlockSize, xBlockSize, yBlockSize);
      }
   }
},
//...
```

How will that perform ? If only 1 or 2 grid elements you won't see much difference but the more grid elements the better the performance should be (cannot test as I don't have the full code).

If you see that it improves the performance you should apply it to the other functions as well. You should also see if you can put some of those `this.*` to local vars instead in the parent scope and pass them in as parameters to the functions.

Comment: Good suggestions on using local vars.  I had assumed that since it's a reference to the local object that the lookup time would be minimal but I gota boost of 16% performance in the math sections.  (only about a 4% total performance gain but still a cheap way to get a little more speed.  (edits above at end)

As for for vs while, the latest results on JSPerf seem to indicate that for is actually marginally faster than while these days but the difference is quite small.

Comment: @DanHeidel yeah, the JS engines are constantly improving. Things that was fast/slow in the past are becoming very equal in performance nowadays. As to the reference time, it is indeed faster when it is enclosed, but the interpreter still has to go through all the properties on the branch. If you have two branches (this.branch.*) it has to do it there as well which is exponential in time (looking away from possible interpreter optimizations).

Comment: @DanHeidel Also remember that the object is self has a lot of branches in the current state (many probably unnecessary). If you split operations into many small internal functions (if possible in your scenario) which are invoked in succession internally you will gain some increase in performance as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  I'm used to C in embedded systems and all the automated abstraction and behind-the-scenes stuff in the browser is taking a bit of time to get used to.